# ios TestFlight - Invitation link not arrived

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am trying to invite a colleague of mine to test an ios flutter app with TestFlight but he keeps not getting them. 
I have been following the official documentation and all the possible forums on the subject (on stack overflow and the official Apple forum) but the solutions appear to be outdated so many things written are no longer valid. 
I have tried several times to remove the test group and the tester user and reinstall it. 
I have also tried several times to resubmit the invitation but nothing has changed. 
Do you know how to fix this or can you recommend an updated official guide?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same situation. Glad I’m not alone. Assuming it’s with Apples email as I didn’t get any email notifications about a new TestFlight build. But the email address is working and receiving email.